# Rails Find Related Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out a way to find related content on my Rails blog by utilizing the "name" field that I have. Is there any way to find closely related posts in the database based on similarity of the "name" field.

For example:

```
Post 1 name field = this-similarity-other-thing
```

and

```
Post 2 name field = this-similarity-something-else
```

Is there any way I can search and find "this-similarity" as being roughly the same in the string, thus being able to pull it from the database and allow it to be shown in the view as related content?

Comment: What does "roughly the same" mean? Is "that-similarity-other-thing" roughly the same? Is "foo-bar-other-thing" roughly the same? Is "this-similar-ity-other-thing" roughly the same?

Comment: Would be only "this-similarity" — there are actually quite a few fields under the name record that are 50% match or more.

Definitely not "this-similar-ity-other-thing"

Comment: Perhaps look at the `LIKE` query operator...

Comment: You can do a wildcard search in ActiveRecord like: `Post.where("name ILIKE '%search-term%')`. This is for a Postgress DB other query engines may have different syntax for ILIKE. ILIKE is case insensitive.

Comment: How would I do ```Post.where("name ILIKE '%search-term%')``` against two name fields? Would it be ```Post.where("@post.name ILIKE '@all_posts.name')```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for in Rails, but this is how I would do it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT b.name
  FROM blogs b
  WHERE b.name LIKE 'this-similarity-%'
```

Perhaps the Rails syntax would be something like:

```rb
Post.where("name ILIKE 'this-similarity%'")
```

Of course, how you get the context of the post you're currently (what I hard-coded as `'this-similarity%'`) on will depend on your implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just match on a substring, you can use a wildcard

```
Post.where("name LIKE '%substring%'")
```

if you want to incorporate something more flexible, you can try to get more advanced with ransack and elasticsearch

Comment: This has come close but the issue is that I have multiple name strings. For example ```similarity-model-one, similarity-model-two, similarity-model-three``` and I can't figure out how to strip "model-one, model-two, model-three" from the name field in order to find matches that end up working with something like this ```@related_posts = Post.where("name LIKE '%#{@post.name}'")```

Comment: @PatrickA. - i think ransack can help you put together searches among multiple fields. I'm afraid i don't know exactly how it's done or if there's a simple way to do it without ransack.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SIMILAR TO` instead of `LIKE` - it allows to work with regular expressions

```
names = ['first', 'second', 'third'].join('|') # it gives "first|second|third" string
similar = Post.where("name SIMILAR TO '%(#{names})%'")
```